# Custom item in enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, counters

I would like to have an `enumerate` - list in which, after `1, 2, 3, 4,`
 I need to put `4bis`.

How to do it?

Comment: Shortest way: `\item[4bis] your text` ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: so easy? I know see that numbers and "4bis" are aligned on the right. Is it possible to have the 4 and 4bis aligned on the left?

Comment: Should be possible, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aligning the label left is easy with `align=left` from `enumitem` package. The special item can be set with `\item[4bis]`, but this is only a strategy, if this does not occur very often.

- If the features of the `enumerate` package are requested, change to `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` here.
- If the label should be wider, just say `labelwidth=40pt`, for example, in the option list of `\begin{enumerate}`

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
\item One 
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item[4bis] Some with four again
\item Other stuff
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]